# Error too long. Maximum length is 8000. Usando OPENQUERY en SQL

Tags: sql, tsql, transact-sql, microsoft-sql

estoy intentando añadir una subconsulta dentro de un OPENQUERY, utilizando una tabla temporal previamente creada , esto para no recurrir a un cursor que ejecute el openquery 1 a 1 por temas de performance

he hecho lo siguiente

```
SELECT Top 1000 CodigoCliente 
INTO #Prueba
FROM Clientes

 
DECLARE @TSQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @TSQL = '
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(CONEXION,''
SELECT 
 CU.Code
,CU.Name

FROM Clients CU
WHERE CU.Code IN ('
+  STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(p.CodigoCliente AS VARCHAR)
            FROM #Prueba p
             FOR XML PATH('')
         ),1,1,''
        )
+')'')'


EXEC(@TSQL)
```

El cual me funciona perfecto para pocos registros, sin embargo cuando utilizo arriba de los 4,000 registros ya me comienza a salir este error

```
The character string that starts with '
SELECT 
 CU.Code
,CU.Name

FROM Clients CU
WHERE CU.Code IN (4080,4081,4082,4083,4084,4085,4086,4087,40' is too long. Maximum length is 8000.
```

Como puedo solucionar este error? para poder usar cualquier cantidad de registros como subconsulta dentro del openquery

Comment: Por curiosidad... esa lista que te devuelve es continua?? Porque si es continua, puedes usar algo como `where CU.Code between (min, max)` habiendo obtenido antes los min y max en vez de *todos* los valores.

Comment: esa lista de esa tabla temporal, contiene los codigos de clientes y son alrededor de 400,000 codigos de clientes, los necesito todos

Comment: Empiezas hablando de que haces este cambio por temas de performance y luego quieres meter medio millón de ids en una lista y mirar si existe el elemento en ella para cada fila?? Uffff, estás seguro de que eso te mejora la query??? La mejor opción sería crear una tabla temporal con los valores de las id que te interesan y hacer un inner join contra esa tabla, evitas completamente el `in`. Sigo pensando que si las id son consecutivas, o simplemente quieres usarlas todas, puedes usar un `between MIN and MAX` en vez de un `in` tan enorme

Comment: Las ID no son consecutivas, como seria hacer el inner join dentro del OpenQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que si hablamos de perfomance es mejor migrar esa información a la base de datos que estas utilizando y solo mantenerla actualizada desde la db externa.

Los datos de los clientes no cambian mucho en el tiempo.

Una solución no la mas optima talvez, dependiendo del como está el sistemas sería colocar la ultima fecha de actualización y solo actualizar los clientes que fueron actualizados en la db externa hacia la db actual, y luego realizar la consulta de la tabla (db actual) directamente.